# How does this equation result with meter cubed in the denominator?

Tags: unit-of-measure

The following equation is in my text book:

$1.01 x10^5kg/m-s^2 \over (0.760m)(9.81m/s^2)$

and the following answer is this:

${1.35x10^4kg/m^3 }$

my question is this: where did the ${m^3}$ come from?

If I multiply .760m and 9.81m then I get ${7.4556m^2}$

even if the numerator has is $m^-1$, wouldn't the law of of exponents state that it's going to be -1 - 2 because you subtract the numerator exponent from the denominator exponent.

Comment: there is $m^{-1}$ in numetator and $m^2$ in denominator.

Comment: where do you see a negative one?

Comment: the numerator isn't m minus. it's actually supposed to be a shorter dash, as it deals with pressure Patm.

Comment: $kg/m$ means $kg.m^{-1}$

Comment: Really???? can you refer this to a rule or law on some website that explains this?

Comment: For example $kg/m^3$ is equal to $kg.m^{-3}$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with division algebras.

Comment: Abdallah, does that dot between the kg and the $m^3$ mean multiplication or is it just a dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in your question.  The whole units of the numerator are $\frac {kg}{m\cdot s^2}$. The dash is an unfortunate symbol for multiplication.  The numerator has length units of $m^{-1}$, the denominator has length units of $m^2$, so the fraction has length units of $-1-2=-3$.  The answer has $m^3$ in the denominator, so length units of $m^{-3}$

Comment: Thank you so much. You explained it exactly as i needed it. Is there a calculator than can spit out an answer for equations like this?

Comment: I don't know.  You just count powers in the numerator and denominator of each unit.  Maybe Alpha knows newtons are $kg \cdot m^2/s^2$ but I don't know.